# Kafka LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE, even though topic has leader

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We have 3 Kafka (1.0.0) nodes, and one topic with 4 partitions and 3 replicas. The topic normally looks like this:

```
Topic:MissionControlTopic   PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
Topic: MissionControlTopic  Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 2,1,0
Topic: MissionControlTopic  Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 2,1,0
Topic: MissionControlTopic  Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 2,1,0
Topic: MissionControlTopic  Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,2,1 Isr: 2,1,0
```

Every once in a while, node 0 stops responding (this is *an* issue but not *the* issue). When that happens, the other two nodes correctly take over its partitions, and the topic looks like this:

```
Topic:MissionControlTopic   PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
Topic: MissionControlTopic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 2,1
Topic: MissionControlTopic  Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 2,1
Topic: MissionControlTopic  Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 2,1
Topic: MissionControlTopic  Partition: 3    Leader: 2   Replicas: 0,2,1 Isr: 2,1
```

At this point, most (but not all) producers and consumers cannot write to/read from Kafka and keep logging `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` exceptions (first issue). Once node 0 has been restored and the leaders have been rebalanced, the apps still keep logging the exceptions (second issue). Only after the apps are restarted do they reconnect and start working properly. As you might imagine it is quite impractical to restart all apps whenever a Kafka node has an issue.

I'm not sure what information would be useful here to try and troubleshoot this. We have scoured the internet for information but we haven't found anything to suggest our config has any obvious mistakes. I have even reproduced the issue locally and the apps reconnect correctly once the node is restored.

This is the code which writes to Kafka:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaUrl);
properties.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
properties.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
properties.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 10);
properties.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.getCanonicalName());
properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericEventSerializer.getCanonicalName());

kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

// And at some later point...
kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, event), (metadata, exception) -> {
    if (exception != null)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to write to Kafka", exception);
    }
});
```

And this is the code that reads from it:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaHostString);
props.put("group.id", consumerGroupId);
props.put("request.timeout.ms", 15000);
props.put("session.timeout.ms", 10000);
props.put("max.poll.records", 10000);
props.put("batch.size", 6400000);

Consumer<String, GenericEvent> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new GenericEventDeserializer());
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic));

// And at some later point ...
records = consumer.poll(pollTimeout);
consumer.commitSync();
```

`advertised.host.name`, `advertised.port`, and `advertised.listeners` are all set in `server.properties`.